# How can I set a margin bottom to an overflow:auto div within a flex container?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I can't set margin bottom to my  element which have table.

I have 3

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="navbar">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

The problem is when i want set margin-bottom to my content element.

CSS

```
.main {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}
```

Navbar from bootstrap:
`class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light navbar-bg"`

Also in my content div i have body of the site which have all in div class wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-bottom: 100px

}
```

Adding margin-bottom to my wrapper don't change anything.
Can me please help figure out where i have problem ?

Comment: Hello, to be honest your post is not so clear for two reasons: you mentioned .wrapper class and margin-bottom, however i don't see them in your HTML code,  
can you please update your post to provide more informations about it ?

Comment: The <div class="wrapper"> have content of my site (there is table). Under this table i want to make for example  margin-bottom: 100px. When i add this to my .wrapper css it not work. I dont know why

Comment: to be honest I can not help you if you don't provide the full code including the div.wrapper element and its partial table element at least. the code you provided above is missing the two main concerned elements